# Borders going inwards instead of outwards

Tags: css, firefox, border

My borders are going inwards instead of the normal outwards. I have no idea what is going on because there is nothing new I'm doing in my code. Is there any simple explanation to this (and solution)?

[image]

It works fine in other browsers. I'm on FF33.

**Update**
http://jsfiddle.net/8Lyrnm5s/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="post_section">
    <div class="repetitive_q_wrap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.post_section {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.post {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #295269 #ddd #ddd;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 15px 1px;
  padding: 30px 50px;
}
```

Comment: my only possible explanation is you did that with Photoshop or similar graphic software, so the solution would be to stop doing it. If you expect an answer related to code, please post CODE

Comment: Haha, I wish it was PS..! I'll post the code but I have to clean it up first to make it readable.

Comment: I see no difference between Chrome and FF, on mac

Comment: Firefox has a long standing margin bug. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791 There are numerous test cases and i've encountered the bug relating to margin top a few times myself.